# How do I log ajax requests in Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-analytics

I am trying to log JavaScript events such as AJAX and click events using Google Analytics.

I have done some reading on Google Analytics and it seems I need to use _trackPageView and _trackEvent. I have put this is my code as a JavaScript function that I call as needed. Here is the code:

> var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker();
>   pageTracker._trackPageview(url);
>   var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker();
>   pageTracker._trackEvent(category, action, item);

I have verified using FireBug that the HTTP requests are going out successfully when I call this chunk of JavaScript code and I am not receiving any errors. However, the page views and events that I am logging using this code is not working. I do not see any entries in the analytics reports.

**Update**
Adding my google analytics code in order to help with versioning:

> var _gaq = _gaq || [];
>       _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'XXXXXX']);
>       _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
>   
>       (function () {
>           var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
>           ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www')   + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
>           var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
>       })();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Async tracking code then your trackevent code should look like this:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Baby\'s First Birthday']);
```

rather than this

```
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker();
pageTracker._trackEvent(category, action, item);
```

It is confusing because the help documents don't seem to be fully updated. The top of the help document for this feature still uses the old format but if you keep going down you will see the rest of the samples have been updated correctly:

- http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html

Comment: The tracking code has been in place for over a week with no hits for either trackEvent or trackPageView. We're using trackPageView when downloading pages using Ajax. We're logging the Ajax url as a page view. We're using trackEvent for things like tabbing and scrolling. However, neither are working.

Comment: It sounds like you will have the asynchronous code then if your code is only a week old. This means your tracking code calls should look more like _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']); rather than the example you provided.

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncUsageGuide.html

Comment: I've updated my question with my google analytics code. It looks like what you are suggesting. The original code I provide was the JavaScript code I was using to log the page view or event view.

Comment: i have also completely changed my answer as it seems you understand the high level concepts and you just need help with specific javascript