# Google Analytics Goal for ajax form submissions not scoring the goals

Tags: ajax, forms, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have tried this answer but it is not working properly:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33207127/9124081

This answer possibly needs to be updated for more recent versions of GA. I did the following to set up goals when the page is submitted via ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/some/page/that/does/not/have/ga/on/it.php",
    data: { formData:formData },
    success: function() {
        // Some success message to user.
        // Create a virtual page view that you can track in GA.
        ga('send', {
            'hitType' : 'pageview',
            'page' : '/contact-us-success' // Virtual page (aka, does not actually exist) that you can now track in GA Goals as a destination page.
        });
    }
});
```

Then in GA -> Admin -> Goals -> New Goal

(1) Goal setup - Custom
(2) Goal description -> choose 'Destination'.
(3) Goal details -> Destination Equals to /contact-us-success

Hope this helps someone else.

And this is my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Antes de enviar
        $('#formdata').submit(function() {
            $('#botonenviar').hide();
            $('#loader').show();
            // Enviamos el formulario usando AJAX
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                data: $(this).serialize(),

                // Mostramos un mensaje segun respuesta de PHP
                success: function(rsp) {



                    if(rsp=='error')
                        $('#fracaso').show(),
                        $('#loader').hide()
                        ;
                    else
                        $('#exito').show(),
                        $('#loader').hide(),
                        ga('send', {
            'hitType' : 'pageview',
            'page' : '/contact-us-success' // Virtual page (aka, does not actually exist) that you can now track in GA Goals as a destination page.
        });


                }



            })        
            return false;
        }); 
    })
```

No console errors, I have disable adblockers even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are mentioning the `ga` object:

```
ga('send','event', <Category>, <Action>, <Label>);
```

EDIT: You use tag manager, therefore you have to use the dataLayer object.

This is  the correct syntax to track a contact form, then you create a Goal in Analytics

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Antes de enviar
    $('#formdata').submit(function() {
        $('#botonenviar').hide();
        $('#loader').show();
        // Enviamos el formulario usando AJAX
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
        // Mostramos un mensaje segun respuesta de PHP
        success: function(rsp) {
            if(rsp=='error')
                $('#fracaso').show(),
                $('#loader').hide();
            else
                //ga('send','event','form','submitted');
                dataLayer = dataLayer || []; // Safe init
                dataLayer.push({'event' : 'form_submitted'});
                $('#exito').show(),
                $('#loader').hide(),
    }
})
```

Go into Tag Manager, create a new tag with the following:

Tag configuration - Universal Analytics - Event.

Event Category and Event Action you can put what you prefer as long as it's the same as what you put in the Goal information. Remember to also set the Google Analytics property ID into a Google Analytics variable.

Trigger configuration - Custom event, all custom events and you put `form_submitted` inside the textbox.

And then, if needed you create an [Event Goal](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012040?hl=en) . You test them from `Real time > Events` and analyze them through `Behaviour > Events`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I attached an image from analytics is this correct? https://i.imgur.com/d7yE4MT.png I am getting error still

Comment: That is correct. Note that some goals may take up to 6h before updating, check as I said in Behaviour > Events > Overview and remember to put today's date.

Comment: I am using google tag manager I just saw, i thought I was using analytics.js. Can it still work?

Comment: I will edit my answer, you will need to use a custom event.

Comment: It worked! Nice. I didn´t quite understand how to link  tag manager event with an individual analytics event so I can track separated analytics events?